# cannot find symbol error while compiling a java class containing other class type object

Tags: java, package

I have a java package which contains two classes. Class A and Class B. I need to create an object of A type in class B. I don't know what is happening. Please someone help me out.

**package pack;**

**class A**

**class B**

I'm using JDK1.5 and tomcat and placed them in java folder in my D drive.

**D:\java\jdk1.5**

**D:\java\tomcat**

Right now, my package folder is also in above location

**D:\java\pack**

Below is how i am compiling my java class files.

**Step 1: Compiling A.java**

D:\Java\pack>**set path=D:\java\jdk1.5\bin** (setting up path for jdk1.5 compiler)

D:\Java\pack>**javac A.java** (Successfuly compiled and formed **A.class**)

**Step 1: Compiling B.java**

D:\Java\pack>**javac B.java** (here, i get an error message )

Below is the ERROR message

**Error Message**

**D:\Java\pack>javac B.java**

**B.java:9: cannot find symbol**

**symbol  : class A**

**location: class pack.B**

```
            A a = new A();    //creating an object of A type
            ^
```

**B.java:9: cannot find symbol**

**symbol  : class A**

**location: class pack.B**

```
            A a = new A();      //creating an object of A type
                      ^
```

**2 errors**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javac pack\A.java pack\B.java
```

will do the trick. The compiler has to be able to resolve everything in one invocation. If it's looking for

```
pack.B
```

then that corresponds to

```
pack\B.java
```

in the directory structure

Comment: **@Brian Agnew** with your trick. Both A.java and B.java are compiled successfully. Using a jsp page, i just set the value variable user that belongs to A.class 

(`public void setName(String name){this.name = name}`)

(`public String getName(){return name;}`)
 
i want to access getName function in B.class where i am getting null. I created an A type object in class B and call 

`public String getTemp(){B obj = new B(); temp = obj.getName(); return temp;} //inside B class`
 
the variable **temp** should contains the value that i have set in A class. But it displays Null.