# got an error message while compiling a java class that contains object of other type

Tags: java

I'm new to java programming language. I made a package name pack. Which contains two java classes A.java and B.java. I'm using jdk1.5 and tomcat. I want to create an object of A type and place it in B.java. Below is how i am trying to do this but getting two error messages.

**package pack;**

**A.java**

```
public class A {

        private String str;

    public A(){} //constructor method
    public void setName(String str){
        this.str = str;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return str;
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
public class B {

        private String temp;

    public B(){} //constructor method

    public String getTemp(){
        A a = new A();      //creating an object of A type
        temp = a.getName();  //assigning the value of getName method to temp variable
        return temp;        // returning temp variable  
    }
}
```

Jdk1.5, tomcat and package pack are in the below directory

**D:\java>**

Below are the steps that i am taking to compile A.java and B.java

**compiling A.java**

```
D:\>cd java
D:\Java>cd pack
D:\Java\pack>set path=D:\java\jdk1.5\bin  (**setting up path of jdk1.5**)
D:\Java\pack>javac A.java (**Compiling A.java. Compiled it successfully**)
```

**compiling B.java**

```
D:\Java\pack>javac A.java (**Compiling B.java. Unable to compile**)

**(Error Message is below)**

D:\Java\pack>javac B.java
B.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class A
location: class pack.B
                A a = new A();      //creating an object of A type
                ^
B.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class A
location: class pack.B
                A a = new A();      //creating an object of A type
                          ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Is there 'package pack;' statement in both Classes A & B?

Comment: Import the class A to B..[Possible Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472319/cannot-find-symbol-error-while-compiling-a-java-class-containing-other-class-typ)

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question over and over again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472319/cannot-find-symbol-error-while-compiling-a-java-class-containing-other-class-typ

Comment: Because i am not getting the best answer that can work for me. I am trying to explain my problem in different ways. If i am violating the rules of this forum. I am sorry about it.

Comment: **@Saurabh** thanks for your reply. The package pack statement is in both classes at the top.

Comment: **@ATR** thanks for your reply. I tried to import A but it still does not working.

Comment: import the class A into class b. Use the fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of compiling your classes from the directory `D:\Java\pack`, go to the base directory of the package, `D:\Java`, and compile and run from there:

```
D:\Java> javac pack\A.java
D:\Java> javac pack\B.java
```

Make sure you do **not** have the `CLASSPATH` environment variable set, or specify the classpath with the `-cp` option:

```
D:\Java> javac -cp . pack\A.java
D:\Java> javac -cp . pack\B.java
```

(Note: `-cp .` means that you include the current directory, indicated by `.`, in the classpath).

Comment: **@Jesper** thanks for your response. I've tried both of your methods. Both files compiled successfully. I pasted pack folder in this directory **D:\Java\tomcat\examples\WEB-INF\classes**. I opened browser and open my jsp page to check its working or not. I created two objects on my jsp page after importing the package pack. `A a = new A();` and `B b = new B();`. 

`a.setName("my message");
out.println(a.getName()+"<br>"); // this displays my message
out.println(b.getTemp()); //this displays null`

instead of displaying **null** it should display **my message** too. Its not working

Comment: You didn't say anything about a webapp before. Are you getting errors? If so, then what errors?

Comment: **@Jesper** i am sorry i did not mention. It does not give any errors when i check in the browser. I want to set values of class A using its object and its working fine. But, when i try to get the value of A class method into B class. It shows null.

Comment: That sounds like a problem that's completely unrelated to the classpath issue that your original question is about. But looking at what your `getTemp()` method in class `B` does, it's not surprising. You're making a new `A` object that does not have a name set. When you get the name that's not set, you get `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there's a package statement in both class A and class B

A.java

```
package pack;
public class A{
....
}
```

B.java

```
package pack;
public class B{
...
}
```

Comment: **@andypp** thanks for your reply. Package statement is in both classes already.